# $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{p^3}$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, wreath-product

Let $p$ be a prime.  Prove that $(\mathbb{Z}_p\wr\mathbb{Z}_p)\wr \mathbb{Z}_p$ is isomorphic to a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_{p^3}$. Here, $\wr$ denotes the wreath product and $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the cyclic group of order $p$. Please explain in detail.

Comment: This is advanced-basic group theory: wreath product and stuff. You surely already did something. Please write down your own work on this.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can you give a good reference for its proof?

Comment: Yes, take Huppert's book on finite groups.

Comment: IIRC this is (in full generality) a guided exercise in Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*. See [Ted's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156364/11619) for a nice alternative description. The description in terms of automorphisms of a full binary tree for the 2-Sylow subgroups of $S_{2^n}$ is particularly nice!

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_n$ is indeed known: The Sylow $p$-subgroup of the symmetric group on $n=p^k$ letters is
$$ \underbrace{C_p \wr C_p \wr \cdots \wr C_p}_{k}, $$
that is, an $k$-fold wreath product of cyclic groups of order $p$. See Huppert, Endliche Gruppen I, Satz III.15.3 for a proof.

Comment: Huppert's Endliche Gruppen I, one of the most awesome books in group theory,  and **still** there is not a traduction to english! I guess we got used to the german language and to the frightening gothic letters (much worse than the language itself...)

Comment: I still have books at home full of gothic letters...it took me a while to be able to read it. A bit of cyrillic is also awesome, like the Tate-Shafarevich group $Ш_{E/K}$.