# Sylow subgroup of $S_{p^2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find Sylow p-subgroup (at least 1) of $S_{p^2}$.
We know that $|S_{p^2}|=(p^2)!$ and hence $|P|=p^{p+1}$ (where P is p-subgroup).
How can I describe this subgroup?

Comment: See [this answer by Ted](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/156364/11619) for an IMO intresting description of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_{p^n}$ as kind of graph automorphisms. The case $p=2$ when we get these groups as automorphisms of the binary tree is particularly nice. Anyway, you get this group as the $n$-fold wreath product $(C_p\wr(\cdots(C_p\wr C_p)\cdots)\wr C_p)\wr C_p$.

Comment: You can also show this inductively, by dividing $\{1,\ldots,p^n\}$ into $p$ subsets $\Omega_1,\ldots,\Omega_p$ of length $p^{n-1}$, have $p$ copies of a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $S_{p^{n-1}}$ act on each $\Omega_i$ and then $C_p$ acts on the set $\{\Omega_1,\ldots,\Omega_p\}$ to show that the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^n}$ is $P\wr C_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the subgroup of permutations on $1,2,3,\dots, p^n$ that permute the subsets $\{1,2,3,\dots,p\},\{p+1,p+2,\dots,2p\}, \{2p+1,2p+2,\dots, 3p\},\dots, \{p(p-1)+1,\dots,p^2\}$ cyclically, and  also permute the elements inside each group cyclically.

There are $p^p$ ways to permute the subsetes internally and there are $p$ ways to permute them externally. So this subgroup has $p^{p+1}$ elements.

Comment: You beat me to it! You might like to note that this is isomorphic to the [wreath product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) $C_p\wr C_p$

Comment: interesting  I didn't know what that was.