# 2-Sylow subgroup of $S_6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

I'm asked to find the 2-Sylow subgroups of the symmetric group $S_3$ using a certain method that is to find the 2-sylow subgroup of $S_{2^k}$. This method is illustrated in *I.N.Herstein*'s "TOPICS IN ALGEBRA" book.  I understand the illustration in the book but don't know how to apply them to this problem since 6 is not a power of 2.  I saw the solution to this problem but couldn't understand some points in it either. I'll give an outline of the solution that I saw.

Solution: divide $1,2,3,4,5,6$ in 3 clumps $\{1,2\},\{3 ,4\},\{5,6\}$

Then define $\sigma =(1 3)(2  4)$

Why?! In the book it's defined in the proof that $\sigma$ should be like
$\sigma =(1  3 5)( 2  4  6)$ why do they change it into 2 cycles to this problem?! I thought that they consider $S_4$ and then later embed it into $S_6$ since 4 is a power of 2.  But then again

The first 2- Sylow subgroup is defined as $$P_1 = \{(
1 2)\}$$
$$P_2 = \sigma^{-1}P_1\sigma =\{(
4 3)\}$$
$$P_3 = \sigma^{-2}P_1\sigma^2 =\{(
56)\}$$
How?! Do they choose $P_3$ or calculate it somehow?

It's given that the 2-sylow subgroup P in $S_8$ is given by
$$P=\{(
1 2),(
56 ) , (1 3)(2 4)\}$$

Where did $P_3 $ go?!

Can anyone analyse and explain this. Or suggest any other way to prove this using the same method illustrated in the book as for $S_{p^k}$?!

Comment: Note that $S_n\times S_m$ embeds in $S_{m+n}$, and $\lvert S_{n+m}:S_n\times S_m\rvert$ is prime to $p$ when (conditions).

Comment: @user10354138 this problem is given before they say anything about direct products.  Is there anyother way u could explain using sylow subgroup properties and permutation properties.

Comment: The $2$-Sylow subgroup of $S_6$ has order $8$; the fact that $6$ is "not a power of $2$" does not seem to be relevant. The rest of your questions are unintelligible without the book in front of me. "In the book it's defined in the proof that $\sigma=(135)(246)$". (Which would be an element of order $3$, and hence rather irrelevant for the purpose of $2$-Sylow subgroups...) "The" proof? Because there is only one? And once you define $\sigma$ once you are never allowed to define a new value of $\sigma$ in any context ever again?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin your first claim is wrong.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Yeah, 16. Doesn't change the main point, though.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  about $\sigma$, in the proof the general definition is given for $\sigma$ for any group $S_{p^k}$. But for this problem if i apply the general definition I'm getting a $\sigma$ of order 3. I don't understand how to choose $\sigma$

Comment: In [this old thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156360/11619) the Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_{22}$ is discussed. I hope that's illuminating enough. It goes like in the (+1) answer by Brauer Suzuki.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2114000/11619) you see Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_{p^2}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen this says a lot on my doubt... thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Since no one wants to elaborate, I give it a try. Let $n=2^{a_1}+\ldots+2^{a_k}$ be the 2-adic expansion of $n$ with $0\le a_1<\ldots <a_k$. Let $P_1$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_{2^{a_1}}$, let $P_2$ be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $\mathrm{Sym}\{2^{a_1}+1,\ldots,2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}\}$ and so on. Check that $P=P_1\times\ldots\times P_k$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: "$\mathrm{Sym}\{2^{a_1}+1,\ldots,2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}\}$" does this mean the symmetric groups with n= $2^{a_1}+1,\ldots,2^{a_1}+2^{a_2} $ ?

Comment: The symmetric group on the set of integers $\{2^{a_1}+1,\ldots,2^{a_1}+2^{a_2}\}$. This group is isomorphic to $S_{2^{a_2}}$.