# $2$-Sylowgroup of $A_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I want to find a $2$-Sylowgroup, i.e. a subgroup of order $8$, of $A_6$.

I think I can solve this problem by brute force but in order to avoid endless calculation I was wondering whether someone could kindly provide a more systematic or efficient approach or any theorems that might help for this question.

Comment: [Relevant](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/D8_in_A6).

Comment: Check out [this older thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/156360/11619). I don't know if it is at the level you seek, but my guess is that it would be close. Once you have a Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_n$ you get one for $A_n$ simply by only including the even permutations.

Comment: There’s an injective homomorphism $S_4\to A_6$ that is the identity on $A_4$ and is defined on odd elements by $\sigma\mapsto \sigma(56)$ and there is a natural embedding $D_8\to S_4$. Combine these maps to get the Sylow subgroup you’re looking for.